# "No gradients" error with a black box custom layer | TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a neural network where given the pure initial state of a quantum circuit (2D-vector), it spits out 2 numbers that would be essentially fed into a quantum computer to get results out. Currently, I have the step where I send a query to the quantum computer as a layer in the model. The quantum computer then will (in this case) spit out two numbers which I'd compare to the theoretical values.

I'm trying to use the MSE loss function and it's yelling at me that I don't have gradients for any variable, i.e. `No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'].`

Here's my code:
Data generation:

```
# TODO extend to complex amplitudes
def generate_Hadamard_data(num_data):
    
    data = []
    
    for _ in range(num_data):
        data_elem = preprocessing.normalize(np.random.rand(1, 2)).tolist()[0]
        data.append(data_elem)
    
    inv_sq2 = 1/np.sqrt(2)
    hadamard = np.array([[inv_sq2, inv_sq2], [inv_sq2, -1*inv_sq2]])
    
    output = [np.matmul(hadamard, state).tolist() for state in data]
    
    data_ten = tf.constant(np.array(data).T, dtype=tf.float32)
    output_ten = tf.constant(np.array(output).T, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    print(output_ten)
    
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_ten), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(output_ten)
```

Custom Layer:

```
class HadamardCircuitLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    '''
    Takes in the initial data (state) and output (pulse params) from the neural network
    and runs it on the backend ibmq_armonk
    '''
    def __init__(self, initial_data, shots=1024):
        super(HadamardCircuitLayer, self).__init__()
        # Unpack data
        data_iterator = initial_data.as_numpy_iterator()
        self.zero_coeffs = data_iterator.next()
        self.one_coeffs = data_iterator.next()
        self.shots = shots
    
    def build(self, shape):
        pass
    
    def call(self, output):
        
        custom_gate = Gate('custom_gate', 1, [])
        provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
        backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_armonk')
        
        post_q_list = []
        
        for a, b, pulse_params in zip(self.zero_coeffs, self.one_coeffs, tf.unstack(output)):
            norm = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
            
            qc = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
            qc.initialize([a/norm, b/norm], 0)
            qc.append(custom_gate, [0])
            qc.measure(0, 0)
            
            pul = pulse_params.numpy()
            
            with pulse.build(backend, name='custom') as my_schedule:
                pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=64, amp=pul[0], sigma=np.e**pul[1]), pulse.drive_channel(0))
                qc.add_calibration(custom_gate, [0], my_schedule)
            
            qc = transpile(qc, backend)
            job = execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=self.shots)
            counts = job.result().get_counts()
            post_q_list.append(np.array([counts["0"]/self.shots, counts["1"]/self.shots]))
        
        output_qten = tf.constant(post_q_list, dtype=tf.float32)
        print(output_qten)
        
        return output_qten
```

Running the actual thing:

````
x_train, y_train = generate_Hadamard_data(1)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_train, y_train))

# arbitrary Dense layers
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
    HadamardCircuitLayer(x_train)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              run_eagerly=True)

# only one epoch for testing rn
model.fit(dataset, epochs=1)

```
````

Comment: AFAIK the customer layers do not work with the sequential api. Might be worth defining the model using the functional API, check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#extend_the_api_using_custom_layers) for more info.

Comment: Ok, I tried implementing the model that way, however it seems that every time it tries to build the HadamardCircuitLayer, it has a problem with `tf,unstack` because it's trying to pass through a variable tensor. I'm ok with trying to solve that problem, however I'm concerned that passing "values" of the variable tensor to the microwave pulse (then to the quantum computer) might cause some problems. Are there any workarounds?